# Customizing JMeter HTML Report with Additional Details

Tags: jmeter, report, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter to conduct load testing for my application and generate an HTML report. However, the default HTML report generated by JMeter provides only basic information, and I would like to add more details to the report.

I have already added additional listeners. However, these metrics are not included in the generated HTML report.

I would like to know how I can customize the JMeter HTML report to include more details and enhance the overall reporting experience. Are there any recommended plugins or tools that can further extend the reporting capabilities of JMeter and provide more detailed and customizable reports?

I have reviewed the JMeter documentation and explored some plugins, but I haven't found clear guidance on how to achieve these customization options for the HTML report.

Any insights, tips, or examples on how to customize the JMeter HTML report and add more details would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box JMeter allows only adding custom charts "over time" with the plotted value of a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables).

If this is what you're looking for check out [Generating customs graphs over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) section

"Heavier" customizations can be performed by amending the contents of the [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.6.1/bin/report-template) folder (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation). It uses [Apache FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) under the hood.

In the majority of cases it's easier to use JMeter's [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) and store the test metrics into the database. Once done you should be able to come up with a visualization solution like [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to represent the test results in the way you want them to appear.

More information:

- [Real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)
- [JMeter + Grafana: How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-grafana)